# Text's `fill` color is overriden by `stroke` in Konva

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I have some Konva Text node, whose `fill` attribute is set to black and `stroke` is set to some other color.
In my canvas it looks as expected. The problem happens when I convert the canvas to base64 image to download it as an image file - in that case the downloaded image looks like in the screenshot below:

(the canvas is on the left side, the right one is the downloaded image)

[image: Text]

As you can see, the stroke color is applied to the text's own color as well.

I created a Codesandbox [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/download-konva-text-node-with-stroke-as-base-64-image-h9smz?file=/src/App.js) with a Text node that has the same attributes as in my environment, here is how that node is created:

```
const text = new Konva.Text({
      x: 26.330053300533024,
      y: 128,
      text: "Add a body text",
      defaultText: "Add a body text",
      fontSize: 22,
      fontFamily: "Montserrat",
      draggable: true,
      name: "text",
      fontStyle: "300",
      id: "textkgrsl68w",
      is_settings: true,
      wrap: "word",
      padding: 5,
      fill: "black",
      opacity: 1,
      isPremium: false,
      width: 183.5,
      visible: true,
      rotation: 0,
      scaleX: 1,
      scaleY: 1,
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      skewX: 0,
      skewY: 0,
      stroke: "rgba(255,0,0,1)",
      strokeWidth: 3.75
    });
```

As you can see, it has the same (incorrect) look - without the inline color. I played with `fontSize` in Codesandbox and when I set it to very big value (like `100`), the text's inline color became visible.
I assumed it can be some `ratio` problem, but as we see on the screenshot, the text's size is similar in both canvas and downloaded image.

How can this be fixed, maybe there is some extra attribute that should also be set?

`konva`: `7.1.4`

`react-konva`: `16.12.0-0`

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED:**

You can use `text.fillAfterStrokeEnabled(true);` to draw fill over stroke.

**Old answer:**

By default `Konva` is drawing fill first then stroke. So it will be a text itself and then stroke around it (that goes overfill part).

Probably one-day Konva will support a different order, but at the current moment `konva@7.1.4` can't do that.

As a workaround just use two `Konva.Text` instances. First for stroke, second for fill.

https://codesandbox.io/s/download-konva-text-node-with-stroke-as-base-64-image-forked-w0z4v